# For which positive integers $n$ does $P(n)$ fail to hold?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, complex-numbers, contest-math

Let $n$ be a natural number and let $z$ be a complex number.
Consider the following proposition:

> $P(n)$:  If $\cos (nz)$ is bounded above by one in absolute value,
>               then $\cos z$ itself is likewise bounded above.

In *[AG, p,53 #4 , soln p.184]* the authors prove that $P(n)$ is true
for the specific value  $n = 3$. Of course, this immediately establishes
validity also for $n = 9$, $27$, etc.  However, it appears to hold for other
values as well.

> **Question:**  For which positive integers $n$ does $P(n)$ fail to hold?

<sub>**Reference:** *[AG] Mathematical Olympiad Challenges by Andreescu & Gelca*.</sub>

Comment: That's an adorable (but useless) title. I'd recommend changing it to one that is more topical.

Comment: What does it mean for $\cos z$ to be bounded above for $z \in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$?

Comment: @GFauxPas I presume the "likewise bounded above" means ..."bounded above by one in absolute value" (just like in the first part of the sentence).

Comment: Oh yes I see. I usually see the word "modulus" for $|z|$, I think that's why I was confused.

Comment: Why not use $nz/3$ is a complex number, so if it's true for $3$,...

Answer (score 1):

For any positive integer $n$, define
$$\alpha_k = \cos\frac{\pi(2k+1)}{2n}\quad\text{ for }\quad k = 0, 1,\ldots, n-1.$$
For any $z \in \mathbb{C}$, we know

$$\cos(nz) = T_n(\cos z) = 2^{n-1}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\cos(z) - \alpha_k\right)$$
where $T_n(x)$ is the $n^{th}$ [Chebyshev's polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the first kind.

Since $\alpha_k = -\alpha_{n-1-k}$, we have

$$\big|T_n(\cos z)\big| = 2^{n-1}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left| \cos(z)^2 - \alpha_k^2 \right|^{1/2}
\ge 2^{n-1} \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \left| |\cos(z)|^2 - \alpha_k^2 \right|^{1/2}
= \big|T_n(|\cos z|)\big|$$

As a result, whenever $|\cos nz| \le 1$, we will have $\big|T_n(|\cos z|)\big| \le 1$. 
Now $|\cos z|$ is a non-negative number and we know
$$T_n(x) =  \cosh(n\cosh^{-1}(x)) > 1\quad\text{ for }x > 1$$
This means whenever $|\cos nz| \le 1$, we will have $|\cos z| \le 1$ too. i.e.
$P(n)$ is true for all positive integer $n$.